# How to deserialize jsonconvert newtonsoft?

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

Hello guys Could you help me? I have the class below

```
public class EmpTraining
{
    public int CodColig { get; set; }
    public string EmpID { get; set; }
    public string Employee { get; set; }
    public string CostCenter { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string WorkstationID { get; set; }
    public string Workstation { get; set; }
    public string Training { get; set; }
    public string CreateDt { get; set; }
    public string DueDt { get; set; }
}
```

And I need to deserialize the json below.

```
{
  "EmployeesTrainings": [
    {
      "CODCOLIGADA": 1,
      "CHAPA": "sample string 2",
      "NOME": "sample string 3",
      "CCUSTO": "sample string 4",
      "Departamento": "sample string 5",
      "CODPOSTO": "sample string 6",
      "POSTO": "sample string 7",
      "TREINAMENTO": "sample string 8",
      "REALIZADO_EM": "2016-04-19T14:17:19.7291778-03:00",
      "VALIDADE": "2016-04-19T14:17:19.7291778-03:00"
    },
    {
      "CODCOLIGADA": 1,
      "CHAPA": "sample string 2",
      "NOME": "sample string 3",
      "CCUSTO": "sample string 4",
      "Departamento": "sample string 5",
      "CODPOSTO": "sample string 6",
      "POSTO": "sample string 7",
      "TREINAMENTO": "sample string 8",
      "REALIZADO_EM": "2016-04-19T14:17:19.7291778-03:00",
      "VALIDADE": "2016-04-19T14:17:19.7291778-03:00"
    }
  ],
  "HasErrors": true,
  "Errors": [
    "sample string 1",
    "sample string 2"
  ]
}
```

Even changing the name of the variables the error keep happening

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Foxconn.Portal.Model.HR.Training.EmpTraining]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g.
>   [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET
>   type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type
>   like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object.
>
> Path 'EmployeesTrainings', line 1, position 22.

The code that is calling the class to deserialize is:

```
public static List<EmpTraining> List(int codColig, string empID, string trainingID,  string workstationID, string status, int? days)
  {


      List<EmpTraining> empList = Api.PostWebApiStr<List<EmpTraining>>(JSON, webApi, Token, timeOut);

      if (empList.Count > 0)
          return empList;

      return new List<EmpTraining>();

  }
```

the class that I'm using to deserialize is that one below.

```
 public static T PostWebApiStr<T>(string data, Uri webApiUrl, Token token, int timeout)
        {

            using (var client = new ExtendedWebClient(webApiUrl, timeout))
            {
                try
                {

                    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";

                    if (token != null)
                    {
                        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = string.Format("{0} {1}", token.TokenType, token.AccessToken);
                    }

                    var response = client.UploadString(webApiUrl, data);

                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response);

                }
                catch (WebException ex)
                {

                    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: There is no similarity between your class and the json. Also you haven't shown any code to map those. So what is your question?

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: What are you running that generates the error? You're only showing the class property declarations.

Comment: Please note that in your error message `accounts.github`is mentioned which is not contained in your JSON example. The error message seems totally unrelated to your example class. Please post the exact source code what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I add the class that I'm using to deserialize and update de error, i made a mistake and put the wrong error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you probably need to use the below class in order to convert your json data to class object

```
public class EmployeesTraining
{
    public int CODCOLIGADA { get; set; }
    public string CHAPA { get; set; }
    public string NOME { get; set; }
    public string CCUSTO { get; set; }
    public string Departamento { get; set; }
    public string CODPOSTO { get; set; }
    public string POSTO { get; set; }
    public string TREINAMENTO { get; set; }
    public string REALIZADO_EM { get; set; }
    public string VALIDADE { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<EmployeesTraining> EmployeesTrainings { get; set; }
    public bool HasErrors { get; set; }
    public List<string> Errors { get; set; }
}
```

You could then look through EmployeeTrainings list for accesing individual employee details

---

use the below link to convert your json data to C# classes http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [attributes](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute__ctor_1.htm) to change the name of the serialized fields:

```
public class EmpTraining
{
    [JsonProperty('CODCOLIGADA')]
    public int CodColig { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty('CHAPA')] 
    public string EmpID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty('NOME')]      
    public string Employee { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty('CCUSTO')]            
    public string CostCenter { get; set; }
    [Jsonproperty('Departamento')]
    public string Department { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty('CODPOSTO']
    public string WorkstationID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty('POSTO')]
    public string Workstation { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty('TREINAMENTO')]
    public string Training { get; set; }    
    [JsonProperty('REALIZADO_EM')]  
    public string CreateDt { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty('VALIDADE')]  
    public string DueDt { get; set; }
}
```

***But*** the error message you supplied does not explain your problem correctly. It says:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CoderwallDotNet.Api.Models.Account]'

so there seems to be another problem around, which can not be answered. Please supply your full code example, otherwise were just guessing.

Comment: Thank You! I used it together with the first answer!